# Listen for new network request in JavsScript

Tags: javascript

I want to fire an event when there is a new network request. I have overwritten the `fetch` by following code,

```
        window.fetch = new Proxy(window.fetch, {
            apply(actualFetch, that, args) {
                const result = Reflect.apply(actualFetch, that, args);

                result.then(() => {
                    if (args.some(i => {
                        return (
                            typeof i === 'string' &&
                            (i?.includes('/example')
                        )
                    })) {
                        console.log('hello')
                    }
                });

                return result;
            }
        });
```

It works only when I make a new request using `fetch` but when I make an `axios` request from different script file (compiled react) it doesn't fire any event. Any idea?

Comment: A service worker is best here, as it can man-in-the-middle any request. You shouldn't overwrite default behaviour like this. Even when frameworks do it it's actually a no-no (looking at you, nextjs).

Comment: *”it works only when I make a new request using `fetch` but when I make an `axios` request…”* because you have overridden `fetch` not `axios`.

Comment: What is the point of `if (args.some(i => { return ( typeof i === 'string' && (i?.includes('/example') ) }))`?

Answer (score 0):

Axios uses the [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) under the hood, instead of the `fetch`

Answer (score 0):

Axios uses the XMLHttpRequest api.

You could still make it work by using interceptors in the axios library, here's an example :

```
// Intercept requests with Axios
axios.interceptors.request.use((c) => {
    // Call your custom logic here
    console.log(c.url);
    return c;
});
```